# Mocking or not registry-like object in phpunit tests

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm facing some difficulties to mock a registry-like object in my tests, this might be because of a wrong design but it always end using $this->at(x) and, IMHO, therefore tightly coupling my test with tested code.

For example, my registry-like object looks like something like this ( remember that its not real code, juste an example ) :

```
class registrylike{
    public function set($k,$v){$this->$k=$v;return $this;}
    public function get($v){return $this->$v;}
}
```

let say my to be tested class is :

```
class main{
    protected $registrylike;

    public function get_ready($registrylike){
        $this->registrylike = $registrylike;
        $this->registrylike->set('k1','v1');
        $this->registrylike->set('k2','v2');
    }
    public function do_something(){
        return sprintf('%s%s',$this->registrylike->get('k1'),$this->registrylike->get('k2'));
    }
}
```

and my (simple) test is :

```
class mainTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected $tested;
    public function setUp() {
        $this->tested= new main;
        $registrymock = $this->getMock('registrylike');
        $registrymock->expects($this->at(2))
        ->method('get')
        ->with('k1')
        ->will($this->returnValue('v1'));
        $registrymock->expects($this->at(3))
        ->method('get')
        ->with('k2')
        ->will($this->returnValue('v2'));
        $this->tested->get_ready($registrymock);
    }
    public function test_do_something(){
        $this->AssertEquals($this->tested->do_something(),'v1v2');
   }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid using $this->at(x)? 
Should I reconsider this design or use a "real" registrylike instance instead of a mocked one?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your mock with [`returnValueMap`.](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php)

```
$valueMap = [['k1', 'v1'], ['k2', 'v2']];

$registryMock->expects($this->exactly(count($valueMap))
    ->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap($valueMap));
```

This method can map any number of parameters to a value.  And now you don't have to worry about the order of the calls and aren't as tightly coupled for this method call.

For verifying the 'set' call, I would use a `withCallback` to verify that parameter.

```
$expectedSetParams = ['k1', 'k2'];

$registryMock->expects($this->exactly(count($expectedSetParams)))
    ->method('set')
    ->with($this->callback(function($p) use($expectedSetParams) {
        return in_array($p, $expectedSetParams);
    }));
```